# Generic Subtype

Tags: java, generics

```
public class Test<T extends Test.Mapper<?>> {
    SomeFactory<T> factory;

    public Test(SomeFactory<T> factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public <V> V handle(T<V> request) { // fails how to get Class<V> of request.getCls() of a mapper or its subtype?
        HttpUriRequest httpUriRequest = factory.get(request); // does not work
        // decode response and return it as an object represented by request.getCls
        return null;
    }

    public interface Mapper<T> {
        Class<T> getCls();
    }

    public interface SomeMapper<T> extends Mapper<T> {
        void doSomeAdditional();
    }

    public interface SomeFactory<T extends Test.Mapper<?>> {
        HttpUriRequest get(T mapper);
    }
}
```

The handle method is a general purpose method that performs an http request and then
decodes the response body into an object that is represented by the Mapper's getCls() method.
I would like this class to handle different subtypes of Mapper since the SomeFactory Implementation is required to access
 some methods only particular to that type

Something along the lines of this

```
SomeFactory<SomeMapper<?>> somefactory = // factory implementation
Test<SomeMapper<?>> test = new Test<SomeMapper<?>>(someFactory);
test.handle(implementation of SomeMapper<Integer>); // should return an instance of Integer
```

Clarification: Basically the instantiation of Test should only handle() types corresponding to the actual type of Test (SomeMapper or Mapper). The handle method can then take any requests of this actual type.

I.E. If it was `Test<SomeMapper<?>> test`
and I have request like

```
ASomeMapper implements SomeMapper<Double> {}
BSomeMapper implements SomeMapper<Integer> {}

test.handle(new ASomeMapper()); // this should return Double
test.handle(new BSomeMapper()); // this shold return Integer
```

Maybe I should redesign?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's acceptable for what you're trying to do, but you can do this:

```
public class Test<V, T extends Test.Mapper<V>> {
    SomeFactory<T> factory;

    public Test(SomeFactory<T> factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public V handle(T request) {
        return null;
    }

    public static interface Mapper<A> {
        Class<A> getCls();
    }

    public interface SomeMapper<T> extends Mapper<T> {
        void doSomeAdditional();
    }

    public interface SomeFactory<T extends Test.Mapper<?>> {
        HttpUriRequest get(T mapper);
    }
}
```

or you can do this, but you'll have to always define parameter while calling the generic method with more than 2 parameters:

```
    public <V, Z extends T> V handle(Z request) {
        return null;
    }
```

You can't further parametrize parameters like what you were trying to do in your example.

Another solution would be to go back 1 step and do this:

```
    public <V> V handle(Test.Mapper<V> request) {
        return null;
    }
```

So you guarantee it to be an appropriate Mapper type, but don't guarantee its implementation.

As far as how you're trying to use it, it's not going to work like that at all. What you're trying to define is generic method (not only class). So basically another parameter has to be supplied to the method, which is defined by assignment.

No matter how you implement this ASomeMapper your line here is not going to compile:

```
test.handle(new ASomeMapper());
```

It will ask you to do the following:

```
Double value = test.handle(new ASomeMapper());
```

Only this way it knows that you actually want to return Double. If ASomeMapper doesn't match the Double parameter, compiler will complain, but if it matches it will compile. Alternatively, if you define it like this:

```
Object value = test.handle(new ASomeMapper());
```

You will still be shown a warning, which should be treated as an error in your case. Because it doesn't really know what you want to return and will return whatever is coded in ASomeMapper without any type checks. If you want to assign it to an Object and still want a type check then you'll have to parametrize the method invocation explicitly.

```
new Test<SomeMapper<?>>(null).<Double>handle(null);
```

Comment: Yes that's what exactly i'm trying to do, so this isn't possible without casting? Since ASomeMapper actual type is known at compile time, can't it deduce that? It is a subtype of SomeMapper.

Comment: I updated my answer with more explanations, but you're kind of mixing 2 things. Generic method with generic class. Your code can support both, but it's hard to mix them together.

Comment: Please look at the end of my answer. It explains why you wouldn't be able to use it as you wanted.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but I don't think this solves my problem. In your first example you are bounding the class so that it can only  handle subtypes of Mapper that are bound exactly with V. This is also the case in your second example since Z just extends T. For your third example, it's a generic method so how would I associate SomeFactory<T> with the generic method's type parameter V. Also what is the difference between  test.handle(new ASomeMapper()); vs Double value = test.handle(new ASomeMapper()); they should be exactly the same thing in terms of compiling; one is just an assignment.

Comment: Also I think  public <V, Z extends T> V handle(Z request) can not return anything else besides NULL without casting.

Comment: None of the examples solve your problem because the problem is not solvable. You have to relax one of the conditions. Maybe you should just rethink this part and design it differently if you want strict type checks.

Comment: Method <V, Z extends T> V handle(Z request) can return anything. It's up to the implementation. You will have to do casting manually though, which kills the concept of type checks. You have to remember that there's no such thing as pure type check. There are always restrictions. C++ has better implementation, but it's not perfect either. Something somewhere will have to do casting. You just have to decide which place is right for that. It better be isolated in a small part of your code.

Comment: Got it thanks. I'll think of another design